# Display error message if value not found mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

Hi i have done research on this topic i did come across a few solutions, although i wasn't able to implement them to my code because i am a beginner to this. My question is basically how can i display a message if value is not found in the MySQL database?

previously searched: [Displaying message when no results found in PHP MySQL search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479977/displaying-message-when-no-results-found-in-php-mysql-search) and [mysql fetch array if no results display message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6200176/mysql-fetch-array-if-no-results-display-message)

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
 <?php
 $customer = $_GET["custID"];
 $conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "localuser", "pass");
mysql_select_db("testdb", $conn)
or die ('Database not found ' . mysql_error() );
$sql = "SELECT orderNumber, customerID, orderDate, shippingDate, shipped FROM orders where customerID = $customer ORDER by orderDate";
$rs = mysql_query($sql, $conn)
or die ('Problem with query' . mysql_error());
?>
<table border="1" summary="Customer Details">
<tr>
<th>Order Number</th>
<th>Customer ID</th>
<th>Order Date</th>
<th>Shipping Date</th>
<th>Shipped</th>
</tr>
<?php
        $results = mysql_fetch_array($rs);
        if ( $results === FALSE )
        {
             echo "No result";
        }
        else
        {
             foreach($results as $item)
             {?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $result["orderNumber"]?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $result["customerID"]?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $result["orderDate"]?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $result["shippingDate"]?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $result["shipped"]?></td>
                </tr>
           <?php  }
        }
mysql_close($conn); ?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So you already found a couple of answers and, since you don't understand them, you're asking for a third one? This process will take forever. Don't you think you should try to understand the answers you have so far?

Comment: BTW, you'd better finish your project quickly. The mysql extension will throw deprecated warnings in PHP 5.5 and will probably be removed in PHP 5.6.

Answer (score 0):

Use `mysql_num_rows()`

```
if(mysql_num_rows($rs) > 0) {
  // got records
}
else {
  // no records found
}
```

Note:

Don't use mysql_* family functions because they are going to deprecated. Start to look into mysqli or pdo

Comment: Updated the code although when correct value is entered no data is displayed, any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

This usage ***if(count($result > 0))***  is wrong. **mysql_fetch_row** always returns FALSE when there is no result. Please see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

You should use sometime like that

```
    <?php
        $results = mysql_fetch_array($rs);
        if ( $results === FALSE )
        {
             echo "No result";
        }
        else
        {
             foreach($results as $item)
             {
                     ...

             }
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: I did try your code as well same thing happens as i mentioned with the code i tried from @GBD the no result found works if no value was returned. Although when a correct value is entered no data is populated within the table, so just stuck on that bit.

Comment: Updated code again, this time error occurs.

Comment: Error about query being incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysql_fetch_array($rs)
if($result)
```

...