# error message doesn't display even there is no data in database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Referring to this topic: [Display error message if value not found mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16250123/display-error-message-if-value-not-found-mysql),

I tried to understand what's the correct method to achieved it, my current code show's me the result from database query but when I put some value that not in database, it just doesn't show the error message or any php coding error.

Here is my php code:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
require_once 'dbconnect.php';

$name = $_POST['name'];

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $sql = "SELECT *
              FROM customer
              WHERE lname  LIKE :name OR
                    fname LIKE :name OR
                    number LIKE :name";

$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute(array('name' => $name));
    $q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

} catch (PDOException $pe) {
    die("Could not connect to the database $dbname :" . $pe->getMessage());
}
```

and here is my html view:

```
            <tbody>
            <?php
            $cs = $q->fetchAll();
            if ( $cs === FALSE ) {
                 echo "The search of $name return no result";
            } else {
            foreach($cs as $r): ?>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="profile.php?name=<?php echo htmlspecialchars($r['slug']) ?>"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($r['fname']), ' ', htmlspecialchars($r['lname']) ?></a></td>
                <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($r['number']) ?></td>
                <td><a href="profile.php?name=<?php echo htmlspecialchars($r['slug']) ?>">View Profile</a></td>
            </tr>
            <?php endforeach;
            } ?>
        </tbody>
```

Kindly advise where did I go wrong?

Comment: Add `$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened. Plus, add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: @Fred-ii- added but not working. I suspect html part doesn't working maybe I putted a wrong if else statement?

Comment: *Hm...* well I see `href="profile.php?name=` and `$name = $_POST['name'];` try `$name = $_GET['name'];` yet, I'm unsure what the question is about. Try that and see. `?name=` is a GET method.

Comment: hi @Fred-ii-, this part `if ( $cs === FALSE ) {
                 echo "The search of $name return no result";
            } else {` doesnt work as it doesn't show me the error message of `The search of $name return no result` when I submit a non database data to query the database. Hope this provide more clearer picture

Comment: Have a look at Fly's answer below, it may explain why. You can also try `if($cs != TRUE)` but am not 100% sure if that will be the expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, nothing is failing with the query itself, so *fetchAll()* won't return false. What it will do, when you run a query that returns no results, is return an empty array.

In this case, you can alter your if statement to read: `if ($cs === false || empty($cs)) {`. Alternatively, you can use `if (!$cs) {` to allow PHP to interpret falsey values, like an empty array.

Source: [PDOStatement::fetchAll()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php#refsect1-pdostatement.fetchall-returnvalues)